# React : TypeError : Cannot read property 'fullname' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

When I try to submit the edited form it throws an error saying full name property value is undefined. I've passed the initial Values to the form when the form is in the edit mode. It displays the values when I visit the edit route but when I edit the values and submit , it throws an error. I am not getting what is wrong? I am using redux forms.

---

Here's the code :

### UserForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import './AddUser.css'

class AddUser extends Component {
    renderInput(formProps) {
        return (
            <div>
                <label>{formProps.label}</label>
                <input {...formProps.input} type={formProps.type} max={formProps.max} autoComplete='off'
                 label={formProps.label} id={formProps.id}/>
                {formProps.meta.touched &&
                (formProps.meta.error && <span>{formProps.meta.error}</span>) }
            </div>
        )
    }

    onSubmit = (formValues) => {
        console.log('formValues', formValues)
        this.props.onSubmit(formValues)
    }


    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props
        const current = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]
        return (
            <div className='container wrapper'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}
            className='form'>
                <div>
                    <label>FullName</label>
                    <Field name='fullname' component={this.renderInput}
                         type='text' />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <Field name='address' component={this.renderInput}
                 type='text' />
                 </div>
                 <div>
                <label>BirthDate</label>
                    <Field name='birthdate' component={this.renderInput}
                         type='date'
                        max={current} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Select Your Gender</label>
                        <Field name='gender' component={this.renderInput} type='radio' value='male'
                           label='Male' />{' '}
                        <Field name='gender' component={this.renderInput} type='radio' value='female'
                             label='Female'/>{' '}
                        <Field name='gender' component={this.renderInput} type='radio' value='other'
                            label='Other' />{' '}
                    </div>
                <div>
                    <label >Select Your Hobbies</label>
                    <Field name='travelling' component={this.renderInput} type='checkbox' value='travelling' 
                    label='Travelling' />
                    <Field name='reading' component={this.renderInput} type='checkbox' value='reading' 
                    label='Reading' />
                    <Field name='gaming' component={this.renderInput} type='checkbox' value='gaming' 
                    label='Gaming' />
                    <Field name='doodling' component={this.renderInput} type='checkbox' value='doodling' 
                    label='Doodling' />
                </div>
                <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const validate = (formValues) => {
    const errors = {}
    if (!formValues.fullname) {
        errors.fullname = 'You must enter a fullname'
    }
    if (!formValues.address) {
        errors.address = 'You must enter the address'
    }
    if(!formValues.birthdate){
        errors.birthdate='Please select your date of birth'
    }
    if(!formValues.gender){
        errors.gender='Please select your gender'
    }
    return errors
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'userform',
    validate: validate
})(AddUser)
```

---

### EditUser.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {editUser} from '../../actions'
import UserForm from './UserForm'

class EditUser extends Component {
    onSubmit=(formValues)=>{
        this.props.editUser(this.props.match.params.id,formValues)
    }
    render() {
        console.log('UserEdit',this.props)
        if(!this.props.user){
            <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        return (<>
            <div>Edit User</div>
            <UserForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
            initialValues={{fullname:this.props.user.fullname,
            address:this.props.user.address,
            birthdate:this.props.user.birthdate,
            gender:this.props.user.gender}}/>
            </>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps=(state,ownProps)=>{
    return {user:state.users[ownProps.match.params.id]}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{
    editUser:editUser
})(EditUser)
```

---

### actions/index.js

```
import {ADD_USER,USERS_LIST,EDIT_USER} from '../actions/types'
import users from '../apis/users'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'
import history from '../history'

export const addUser=(formValues)=>{
    return async (dispatch)=>{
        const userId=uuid()
        const response=await users.post('/users',{...formValues,userId})
        dispatch({
            type:ADD_USER,
            payload:response.data
        })
        history.push('/')
    }
}

export const listAllUsers=()=>{
    return async (dispatch)=>{
        const response=await users.get('/users')
        dispatch({
            type:USERS_LIST,
            payload:response.data
        })
    }
}

export const editUser=(id,formValues)=>{
    return async (dispatch)=>{
        const response=await users.patch(`/users/${id}`,formValues)
        dispatch({
            type:EDIT_USER,
            payload:response.data
        })
        history.push('/')
    }
}
```

---

### reducers/userReducer.js

```
import {ADD_USER,USERS_LIST,EDIT_USER} from '../actions/types'

const userReducer=(state=[],action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_USER:
            return [...state,action.payload]
        case USERS_LIST:
            return [...state,...action.payload]
        case EDIT_USER:
            const updatedUser=action.payload
            const editedUser=state.map((user)=>{
                if(user.id===updatedUser.id){
                    return updatedUser
                }
                return user
            })
            return {users:editedUser}
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default userReducer
```

Comment: This is too much code, so there's a poor chance that someone will actually try to reproduce your problem.
I recommend you to use a debugger and go through the execution stack with your hands, to the place where the error occurs and check why it occurs.

Comment: You gave us a pretty huge load of code but I miss the full error stack trace. It is hard to guess where the error happens and why without error log.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this..

```js
return (<>
            <div>Edit User</div>
            {!!this.props.user &&
            <UserForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
            initialValues={{fullname:this.props.user.fullname,
            address:this.props.user.address,
            birthdate:this.props.user.birthdate,
            gender:this.props.user.gender}}/>}
            </>
        )
```